How to make HideSoftInputOnTapped work with custom handler and hide the soft keyboard
In our project I have a custom entry based on the solution from the https://github.com/zleao/zoft.MauiExtensions.AutoCompleteEntry to change the default border style in iOS to underline only (I won't include this part in the code since it reproduces without it). The problem is, this solution seems to break HideSoftInputOnTapped property for this entry. When I click outside the custom entry when it has focus, it won't lose focus and won't hide the soft keyboard. When I do this with normal Entry in the same view, it works.
Multiplatform control code:
public class UnderlineEntry : Entry
{
    private bool _suppressTextChangedEvent;

    public Command<string> TextChangedCommand
    {
        get { return (Command<string>)GetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextChangedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextChangedCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextChangedCommand),
            typeof(Command<string>),
            typeof(UnderlineEntry), null, BindingMode.OneWay, null, null);

    public void OnTextChanged(string text)
    {
        _suppressTextChangedEvent = true; //prevent loop of events raising, as setting this property will make it back into the native control
        Text = text;
        _suppressTextChangedEvent = false;

        TextChanged?.Invoke(this, new TextChangedEventArgs(null, text));

        if (TextChangedCommand?.CanExecute(Text) == true)
        {
            TextChangedCommand?.Execute(Text);
        }
    }

    public new event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override void OnTextChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        if (!_suppressTextChangedEvent) //Ensure this property changed didn't get call because we were updating it from the native text property
        {
            TextChanged?.Invoke(this, new TextChangedEventArgs(oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }
}

Multiplatform handler code:
public partial class UnderlineEntryHandler: IUnderlineEntryHandler
{
    public UnderlineEntryHandler() : base(Mapper)
    {

    }
    public UnderlineEntryHandler(IPropertyMapper mapper)
        : base(mapper ?? Mapper, CommandMapper)
    {
    }

    static UnderlineEntryHandler()
    {

    }

    public static IPropertyMapper<UnderlineEntry, IUnderlineEntryHandler> Mapper =
        new PropertyMapper<UnderlineEntry, IUnderlineEntryHandler>(ViewHandler.ViewMapper)
        {
#if __IOS__
            [nameof(IEntry.IsEnabled)] = EntryTest.Controls.Handlers.UnderlineEntryHandler.MapIsEnabled,
#endif
            [nameof(IEntry.Background)] = EntryTest.Controls.Handlers.UnderlineEntryHandler.MapBackground,
            [nameof(IEntry.Placeholder)] = EntryTest.Controls.Handlers.UnderlineEntryHandler.MapPlaceholder
        };

    public static CommandMapper<UnderlineEntry, IUnderlineEntryHandler> CommandMapper = new(ViewHandler.ViewCommandMapper)
    {
    };


    UnderlineEntry IUnderlineEntryHandler.VirtualView => VirtualView;

    PlatformView IUnderlineEntryHandler.PlatformView => PlatformView;
}

public interface IUnderlineEntryHandler : IViewHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Maui view
    /// </summary>
    new UnderlineEntry VirtualView { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Platform specific implementation
    /// </summary>
    new PlatformView PlatformView { get; }
}

iOS custom control:
public class IOSUnderlineEntry: MauiTextField
{
}

iOS handler:
public partial class UnderlineEntryHandler: ViewHandler<UnderlineEntry, IOSUnderlineEntry>
{
    protected override IOSUnderlineEntry CreatePlatformView() => new();

    public static void MapText(IUnderlineEntryHandler handler, UnderlineEntry entry) => handler.PlatformView?.UpdateText(entry);

    public static void MapPlaceholder(IUnderlineEntryHandler handler, UnderlineEntry entry) => handler.PlatformView?.UpdatePlaceholder(entry);
}

MauiProgram.cs:
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                })
                .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if IOS

                    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(UnderlineEntry), typeof(UnderlineEntryHandler));
#endif
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }

View
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:EntryTest.Controls"
             x:Class="EntryTest.MainPage"
             HideSoftInputOnTapped="True">

    <ScrollView BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">

            <Entry Placeholder="normal entry"/>
            <controls:UnderlineEntry Placeholder="custom entry"/>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>


